# Accumulate values ​from one df into another

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes and I want to accumulate the value of one of the dataframes in the other. How can I do it?

Dataframe 1:

| Product | Amount | Price | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 12.0 | 15 |
| B | 4 | 20.0 | 15 |
| C | 2 | 4.0 | 15 |
| D | 5 | 30.0 | 15 |

Dataframe 2:

| Product | Amount | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B | 3 | 20.0 |
| C | 2 | 4.0 |

Result:

| Product | Amount | Price | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 12.0 | 15 |
| B | 7 | 20.0 | 15 |
| C | 4 | 4.0 | 15 |
| D | 5 | 30.0 | 15 |

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with aggregate `sum` - necessary all numeric columns without `Product`:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).groupby('Product', as_index=False).sum()
print (df)
  Product  Amount  Price  Total
0       A       1   12.0   15.0
1       B       7   40.0   15.0
2       C       4    8.0   15.0
3       D       5   30.0   15.0
```